# Is it a bad practice to use something?.isEmpty == true

Tags: arrays, swift, string, option-type

I check emptiness of arrays(strings) several times a day and now I use `isEmpty == true` or `isEmpty == false` everywhere. Whether array is optional or not, it's been a good technique for me, if arrays is not optional, it helps to read code faster. However, I easily might be wrong and this might be terrible code.

So I just wanna know how do mature developers check arrays?  I have already tried using `(string ?? "").isEmpty`, `string?.isEmpty ?? true` and so on. There are some extensions like `isNilOrEmpty`, but it seems a bit ugly :c

Comment: “now I use isEmpty == true or isEmpty == false“ You should never do that. A conditional is a Bool. `isEmpty` is a Bool. Hence it is enough to say `if s.isEmpty`. If you have other issues due to Optionals being involved, you need to clarify what your actual situation is.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is off-topic, as it's asking something that is primarily opinion-based. Please see the [help] for more info.

Comment: This is a good question, and as the existing answers show, there are objective, language-specifc reasons for saying that `something?.isempty == true` is poor Swift style. None of the five people who voted to put this on hold appears to have significant reputation in any Swift-related tags, so they likely saw this as a question about whether using `== true` in a conditional is bad style because it's redundant. Join me in voting to reopen this question — I think it's a useful and important topic.

Comment: It's not always the case, but usually `isEmpty` checks are avoidable. If you check `isEmpty`, and then access `array[0]`, `array[array.count - 1]`, etc. on the next line, it's a good indication that you should instead conditionally bind `array.first` or `array.last`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Whether array is optional or not,

This is where you've likely gone wrong. Why is the array optional, and *especially* why is the array optional if empty and nil mean the same thing? If you find yourself asking this question, then you've designed your types incorrectly. The array should just be an array, and you should much earlier in the process have `... ?? []` to make sure that's true if necessary. A type should avoid having multiple values that mean the same thing.

The only time you should have an optional Collection (including String) is when there is a semantic difference between empty and nil, in which case, you need to be testing for that difference.

So no, you should not use `== true` or `== false`. That's poor Swift in most cases because it forces the reader to do mental gymnastics to understand what it means in the `nil` case, but also because it is showing your underlying design problem.

There are times when empty and nil have different meanings. One of my favorite examples is a multi-layered configuration scheme where "nil" means "no setting" and "empty" means that it is explicitly set to empty at this layer. In those cases, optional collections are absolutely appropriate. And it might be acceptable to use `== true` type syntax in those cases (though I typically would use `?? []` instead; that's just style). But these cases are pretty rare in my experience.

Comment: I would argue that, even in the case where there *is* a semantic difference between `nil` and `isEmpty`, modeling it that way is confusing, and you're better off creating some new enum that better describes the semantics. But that's all an aside from the original question.

Comment: @Connor For the multi-level config case, what would you model at as? `.default` and `.set(Value)`? (or maybe `.unset` and `.set(Value)`) It's an interesting argument, but does it give much value over Optional? I hadn't thought about replacing optional in that way.

Comment: Thank you, I did not think that I can easily unwrap arrays in models in the beginning of the process and then use them as usual types.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not mature developer, but, if I had optional collection, I would first unwrap it, for example using optional binding

```
if let array = optionalArray { ... }
```

and then if I knew that collection exists, I would check if collection contains some elements by checking if `isEmpty` is `false`

```
if !array.isEmpty { ... }
```

Which can be simplified in just one `if` statement

```
if let array = optionalArray, !array.isEmpty { ... }
```

---

In case that you have collection of characters

```
let optionalString: String? = "Hey"

if let string = optionalString, !string.isEmpty {
    print("String contains \(string.count) characters") 
    // String contains 3 characters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
guard let array = optionalArray , !array.isEmpty else {return}
```